# javascript manipulating 2 checkboxes from a button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I got a button called Rework, when i click the button two checkboxes has to be appeared and Rework button should be disappeared and in place a submit button has to be appeared . How will i move on with this concept.?

Comment: Are you not using `jQuery`?

Comment: Post some code please..

Comment: iam not comfortable with jquery, but if the solution can be easy in jquery, iam open for that.

Comment: Possible for you to display the function in question? Seeing how you have your current source code and make things much easier to work the changes into place but I would also like to see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjrwLe

```
**HTML**
<input type="button" id="rework-button" value="Rework" onclick="rework()"/>

<div id="checkboxes">
  Check A: <input type="checkbox" />
  Check B: <input type="checkbox" id="check-a" />
</div>


<input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit"/>

**CSS**
#checkboxes,
#submit-button{
  display:none;
}

**JAVASCRIPT**
function rework(){
  document.getElementById("checkboxes").style.display = "block"
  document.getElementById("submit-button").style.display = "block"
  document.getElementById("rework-button").style.display = "none"

}
```

Comment: your checkboxes are already showing so why you set the display as block ?

Comment: Thank you. its working fine. And where will i give the form value? that is <form></form>

Comment: The html that i gave you, will be included inside the form element.
i.e. <form> the html i gave you </form>

Answer (score 0):

understand this and edit as you want:

```
<div class='checkbx' style="display:none;">
    <!--here goes your checkboxes-->
    </div>
    <input type='button' class'button1'/>
    <input type='submit' class'button2'/>
    <script>
    $('.button1').click(function(){
      $('.checkbx').show();
      $('.button2').show();
      $('.button1').hide();

     });
   </script>
```

This is jquery ..Learn Jquery Ok. **code less  Do more**

**Note: just dont forget to include jquery files... read about jquery**

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, when Rework is clicked, if it is not displayed as none, and show the checkboxes and submit button.

```
function reworkClick() {
    if (document.getElementById("Rework").style.display != "none"){
        document.getElementById("Rework").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("Submit").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("checkboxContainer").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="input_box">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
<div class="button"> 
  <input type="button" class="Rework" value="Rework">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.input_box').hide();
        $('.Rework').click(function(){
            $('.button').hide();
            $('.input_box').show();

        });

    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!